# Can't get Asp.net or IIS to display the error

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-10

I am getting this message on my asp.net site:

[image]

I can run it in Visual Studio without issue but once I publish it, I can no longer access the site.

I have tried the following, to no avail:

Adding this to my web.config:

```
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" >
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

Changing the debugging settings in IIS:

[image]

Changing the Error Page settings:

[image]

For some reason, I can access the site from outside the server but not within it so I have no way of getting the error that way. I ran iireset after my changes to see if that made a difference.

I am running Windows 2012R2 and IIS10.

Anyone have any suggestions or can see if I missed something?

Comment: Check your system event log at the server, the exception details should be present there.

Comment: ty, I will do that now!

Comment: That's where I found the error. I should have known to look there but I got so tied up with trying to get it to output in the browser I lost sight. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it!  Tyvm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*the answer accepted by the OP in the comment section below the question*

If you ever have issues in displaying the detailed error information, please consult your system event log. The complete exception information should be present there.